# How to receive data from an Iframe in Dart?

Tags: iframe, dart, postmessage

I know that the only way to communicate with an `iframe` is using the `postMessage` method as follow:

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("my message", window.location.href);
```

but I would like to know how to receive data from the `iframe` after any change on it.

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I would like to do a wysiwyg. I would like to get the data from the Iframe. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If you want an answer you need to provide more concrete  information. I can't see any connection between wysiwyg and data and postmessage.

Comment: Is there any way to send data back from a child Iframe. Something like parentIFrame.Contentwindow.postMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the receiver window, when you receive the message, you get the sender passed with the message and you can send back to this sender.

```
window.onMessage.listen((e) {
  e.source.postMessage({'somedata': 'xxx'}, '*');
});
```

See also

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26351
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel